# iOS code crashes after dispatching and returning from a block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have code in a block like so:

```
// Create thread
dispatch_queue_t syncedQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Synced Email Queue", NULL);

// Run block on another thread called syncedQueue
dispatch_async(syncedQueue, ^{

    [syncedUsers user:user.username withEmails:emails inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

});

UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Welcome" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];

RegisterViewController *registerView = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:registerView animated:YES];
```

In the block, the category function uses Parse and the context to save data and nothing more.

But after the block returns I always get the following error:

```
"Thread X: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=xxxxx)
```

Comment: Are you using single managedobjectcontext for whole app process?

Comment: It appears to be related to the thread. Background thread/ Dispatcher is doing it, make use of dispatch_get_main_queue() method before doing anything on the UI or on your manage context.

Comment: Uh, just a poke in the dark: Make sure any UI related methods are invoked on the main thread, e.g. using performSelectorOnMainThread:

Comment: does the managed context have to be on the main thread, i though it was just ui stuff

Comment: The best practice is to use a NSManagedObjectContext /es of type NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType for using in Background thread/ Dispatcher. You can add notifications in your Core Data class for saving in Main ManagedObjectContext when a save/update operation is performed. http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/